# When I use dompdf in alpine I get a blank image

Tags: laravel, dompdf, alpine-linux

I use dompdf in Laravel for saving pdf.

I've used it well in the past.

A blank screen appears in alpine linux and php8 environments.

For reference, the version of alpine linux is 3.15.

Does anyone have the same problem as me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the value of html5 parser enable to false.

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify the following points.

1. Have you installed the PHP extension GD? (Optional but recommended)
2. Have you passed the image in base64 to dompdf? (It's mandatory for image processing).

Comment: I installed php-gd and  I don't understand about base64, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Yeah sure, base64 is an encryption algorithm. I hope the following code will help you.

`$path = 'myfolder/myimage.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);`